# How to get notified when data is changed on a database in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have this code by how I can get data from a sqllite database and set it to a list view:

```
Cursor cursor = dbAdapter.getAllIncomingData();
            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                Log.d("ADD/EDIT", cursor.getCount() + "");

                int size = cursor.getCount();
                incomingDataList = new ArrayList<IncomingData>(size);
                incomingStringList = new ArrayList<String>(size);
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    String serial = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("serial"));
                    String mapurl = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("mapurl"));
                    String datetime = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("datetime"));
                    // Device device=new Device(id, label, serial,
                    // contact);
                    Device dev = dbAdapter.getDeviceBySerial(serial);
                    IncomingData inData = new IncomingData(serial, mapurl,
                            datetime);
                    inData.setLabel(dev.getLabel());
                    inData.setContact(dev.getContact());

                    incomingDataList.add(inData);
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
                inAdapter = new IncomingDataArrayAdapter(
                        MatchpointHistoryActivity.this, R.layout.history_item,
                        incomingDataList);
                historyList.setAdapter(inAdapter);


            }
```

the data of the database is being updated by receiving sms, and I have written the insertion query in the receiver class, now I want that if the new data is added or deleted then the cursor will get notified and reset the adapter to the listview, I have to relaunch the activity to view the changes, but I need to notify the changes instant. I dont want to use timer to do this stuff all the time, is there any other way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Now I got your question. This also can be done by BroadcastReceiver, now this time it will be your own custom broadcast receiver for e.g., `"com.yourapppackage.DATABASE_CHANGED"`. Whenever you insert/delete data into database at that time send this broadcast.

You have to register your custom receiver inside your list activity and in `onReceive()` method update your list.

e.g.,
inside AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
    android:name=".DatabaseChangedReceiver"
    android:enabled="true" >
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.youapppackage.DATABASE_CHANGED"></action>
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

DatabaseChangedReceiver.java

```
public class DatabaseChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static String ACTION_DATABASE_CHANGED = "com.youapppackage.DATABASE_CHANGED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

Activity which register this receiver,

```
private DatabaseChangedReceiver mReceiver = new DatabaseChangedReceiver() {
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // update your list
   }

}
```

inside database insert/delete method,
NOTE: you need context reference inside database code.

```
....
// code to insert/delete
....

context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(DatabaseChangedReceiver.ACTION_DATABASE_CHANGED));
```

so this will execute code where you've registered DatabaseChangedReceiver in activity.

Comment: I have tried but how can I register it with manifest, what should be the intent filter action name?

Comment: I did everything u said, and in the activity on create I wrote this

private DatabaseChangedReceiver mReceiver = new DatabaseChangedReceiver() {
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   // update your list
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DT CHANGED",
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

 };

but nothing happens :(

Comment: Have you register custom receiver inside activity by using registerReceiver() method ? e.g. in onResume() registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(DatabaseChangedReceiver.ACTION_DATABASE_CHANGED));

Comment: you also need to unregister it in on pause unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14993/discussion-between-kevin-adesara-and-reyjohn)

Answer (score -3):

@Reyjohn. 
You can use the **boolean flag** variable for this.Initially it is set to **false** Whenever insertion or any updation is done then change the flag to **true**. And after that you can simply check if flag is **true** then you have to notifyDataSetChanged() and again set the flag to **false**.

Comment: But how can I know if the data is changed or not?